# Why cant i enter decimal values in input in the following case

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before anything you need to see the effect:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kfkjy/)

As you can see it is a calculator where you can put a value anywhere and covert it to other values, but the problem is that i cant enter decimal int values like 0.3 or 0.999. What is the cause of this?

```
var id = {
    mm: 1,
    cm: 10,
    m: 1000,
    km: 1000000
};

$('input.bx').on('keyup', function() {

    var t = $(this).val();
    var i = id[$(this).attr("id")];
    var v = parseInt(t, 10);

    for (pp in id) {

        if (t !== '') {
            $("#" + pp).val(v / id[pp] * i);
        } else {
            $(".bx").val('');
        }

    }

});

<input type='text' class='bx' id='mm'> Milimeter<br>
<input type='text' class='bx' id='cm'> Centimeter<br>
<input type='text' class='bx' id='m'> Meter<br>
<input type='text' class='bx' id='km'> Kilometer<br>
```

Comment: a working fiddle for u [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cQCmR/)

Comment: @Anil Kumar Please answer this question so i can accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cQCmR/)

you have to use `parseFloat` and dont try to set the current focused element value cause you are over riding it while typing.

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt` is the "problem" since it returns integer - decimal values are not integer but floats. If you want that you must replace it with `parseFloat`.

Comment: Exactly, "decimal int values like 0.3 or 0.999" is a contradiction in itself.

Answer (score 2):

1.First you need to use **parseFloat** because int cant have decimals. 
2.Second i would use **onChange**.
http://jsfiddle.net/Kfkjy/10/

Answer (score 1):

this example is working fine

http://jsfiddle.net/Mohamed_aboelenen/D6T7j/1/

```
$('input.bx').on('keyup', function() {

var t = $(this).val();
var i = id[$(this).attr("id")];
var v = parseFloat(t, 10);
var a = $(this).attr("id"); // the textbox you write in
for (pp in id) {
    if (t !== '' ) {
        if(a != pp){  // make changes to any textbox except the one you write in
        $("#" + pp).val(v / id[pp] * i);
        }
    } else {
        $(".bx").val('');
    }

}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.bx').on('blur', function() {

    var t = $(this).val();
    var i = id[$(this).attr("id")];
    var v = Number(t, 10);

    for (pp in id) {

        if (t !== '') {
            $("#" + pp).val(parseFloat(v / id[pp] * i));
        } else {
            $(".bx").val('');
        }

    }

});
```